# Password reset issue using terminal method

Tags: password

No user accounts are displayed in the window that pops up after I enter the 'resetpassword' command into the terminal.

Is there another way to reset my admin password or fix this issue?

Comment: Are you booted into "Recovery Mode" to use the command resetpassword?

Comment: Yes, that's it. I've also tried cmd + S to go straight into the terminal on start up but that's not working either.

Comment: Does your harddisk show up in the pop up box and is it selected?  Something like "Macintosh HD".

Comment: No, it's completely blank

Comment: Hmm, can you boot into your computer normally and get to the login screen?  Sounds like you have more of an issue with the hard drive not a password.

Comment: I can get into the guest account at the moment, but yes I have been having issues.

Comment: I would try running Disk Repair from Disk Utility in Recovery mode and see if that clears a little bit up for the resetpassword dialog.

Comment: I have done that a few times now but still no luck. Weirdly it keeps saying it's okay on the repair logs.

Answer (score -1):

A wire connecting the hard drive was loose.